# Change Background color of polar plot in ggplot according to a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I have built a polar plot based on the code provided by M.Baggott (http://rpubs.com/mattbagg/circular) to summarize the number events occurring by week throughout the year. Rather than fill the bars by month, is there a way to leave the bars gray and fill the background according to month (i.e., 12 colored pie slices representing month behind the gray frequency bars)? Thanks

[image: Polar Plot Colour][image: Polar Plot Grey]

Here is a small subset of data and my code:

```
Week<- c(30, 21, 20, 26, 24, 22, 26, 26, 30, 25, 23, 23, 22, 24, 23, 22, 26, 20, 20, 23)
```

`Month<- c("July", "May", "May","June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "July", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "July", "May",  "May", "June")`

```
df<- data.frame(Week=Week,Month=Month)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Week)) + 
       geom_histogram(breaks = seq(1, 52), colour = "white") + 
       coord_polar(start = 0) + 
       theme_minimal() + 
       scale_colour_gradient(colours=rainbow(12)) + 
       ylab("Count") + 
       ggtitle("Count by Week") + 
       scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(1, 52), breaks =c(1,5,9,13,18,22,26,31,35,39,44,48),labels=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December"))
```

Comment: You will need to provide minimal data and code example

Comment: I added a small subset and my code as it stands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea:

using `geom_col` to define the colored background with a separate data.frame and a discrete scale that utilizes `geom_bar`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Week)) + 
  geom_col(data = data.frame(seq = as.factor(seq(1, 52)),
                             month =  factor(rep(c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December"), 
                                          times = diff(c(0,5,9,13,18,22,26,31,35,39,44,48,52))),
                                          levels = c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December")),
                             y = 4),
           aes(x = seq, y = y, fill = month), width = 1)+
  geom_bar(colour = "white", stat = "count", show.legend = F) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  ylab("Count") + 
  ggtitle("Count by Week") + 
  coord_polar(start = 0)+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks =c(1,5,9,13,18,22,26,31,35,39,44,48)+2,
                   labels=c("January","February","March","April",
                            "May","June","July","August","September",
                            "October","November", "December"))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. You can set the height dynamically based on the original data, by replacing `y = 4` with `y = max(table(df))`.